# How to launch process programmatically as admin with a NOT admin user logged

Tags: c#

i'm trying to launch a proccess with admin privileges with a not admin user.

If I try this code:

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
processInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe";
            processInfo.Verb = "runas";
            processInfo.UserName = "admin";
            string pass = "adminPAss";
            SecureString pwdSecure = new SecureString();
            foreach (char item in pass)
            {
                pwdSecure.AppendChar(item);
            }
            processInfo.Password = pwdSecure;
            processInfo.Domain = "MyDomain";
            processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            processInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            Console.WriteLine();
            Process process = new Process();
            process = Process.Start(processInfo);
```

The admin user launch notepad++.exe but not with admin privileges.

if I impersonate the admin user and then i try to launch the process:

```
using (WindowsImpersonationContext impersonatedUser = WindowsIdentity.Impersonate(safeTokenHandle.DangerousGetHandle()))
{

    // Check the identity.
    Console.WriteLine("After impersonation: "
        + WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent().Name);
    ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\Notepad++\notepad++.exe";

    processInfo.Verb = "runas";
    processInfo.Domain = "MyDomain";
    processInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
    processInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
    processInfo.LoadUserProfile = true;
    //processInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
    //processInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
    Console.WriteLine();
    Process process = new Process();
    process = Process.Start(processInfo);
    process.WaitForExit();
}
```

the procces is launched wrong.

[image]